# ввод вывод данных

Tags: cmd, perl

Задача заключается в следующем:
Имеем переменную "$image" - с бинарными данными/картинка/.
По старому варианту сохраняем данные в файл:

```
open A, '>img.png';
binmode(A);
print A $image;
close A;
```

Далее выполняем системную команду с сохранением вывода в переменную $res

```
my $res = `tesseract img.png stdout --psm 8 myconf`;
```

Собственно сам вопрос:
Как передать аргументы без сохранения переменной $image в файл, поскольку tesseract предусматривает одновременный ввод и вывод подобной командой:

```
tesseract stdin stdout --psm 8 myconf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use IPC::Open2;

my $pid=open2(my $read, my $write, "tesseract stdin stdout --psm 8 myconf");
# Запускаем команду, при этом получаем два файловых дескриптора
# $write - stdin программы, $read - stdout программы
# $pid - pid запущенного процесса в ОС
print $write $image;  # Пишем изображение на вход программы
close($write); # Закрываем дескриптор вывода, для сообщения программе об окончании ввода
local $/;          # Будем читать сразу весь вывод (а не по одной строчке)
my $res = <$read>; # Читаем
waitpid($pid, 0);  # Получаем код возврата (без этого в системе заведутся зомби)
```

Comment: благодарю, но что-то пустое окно висит, ничего не выводит

Comment: @usr13 Смотрите на чем собственно висит. запустился ли тессеракт, не забыли ли закрыть $write. Не перепутали ли местами read/write. Данный пример я проверял на cat и wc, отработал корректно. кроме того по очень похожей схеме у меня запускается тессеракт в антиспаме, правда там параметры у него другие, вместо stdin и stdout указаны знаки "-". Так что еще проверьте что все верно с его параметрами и не ждет ли он чего нибудь

Comment: @Mike может ему просто нужно результат показать? `say $res;`

Comment: @nörbörnën Думаю там что то другое, он бы не висел, а завершился. И думаю вывод то ТС догадается сделать под свои нужды

Comment: в процессах tesseract висит, если вместо stdin указать файл то отрабатывает, естественно выводится на печать $res, "type 1.png | tesseract stdin stdout --psm 8 myconf" - тоже отрабатывает

Comment: @usr13 Раз висит в процессах, значит продолжает ожидать ввода. Это может быть только одном случае - он не видит завершения окончания данных на stdin. Это в свою очередь может быть если не закрыли $write (думаю это единственная причина). Еще раз убедитесь, что дескриптор в который вы пишите и который закрываете это именно тот, который возвращается через второй параметр open2

Comment: @usr13 Проверил непосредственно на tesseract. Как и ожидалось, удалось завесить не выполнив `close($write)` _перед_ началом чтения из $read. Во всех остальных случаях (нет такой команды, не верные параметры, пустые данные, некорректный файл изображения) происходит завершение

Comment: еще раз все проверил - без изменений, забыл добавить, OC windows, возможно есть зависимость, т.к используются fork'и - а с этим под виндой всегда были проблемы

Comment: @usr13 `$write->autoflush(1)` попробуйте. перед print в него. А еще сделайте какую нибудь печать после каждой строки (не забудьте `$|=1`), интересно на чем оно стопится, на чтении или раньше, еще во время записи.

Comment: на чтении $res = <$read>

Comment: @usr13 Хм, значит tesseract не закрывает свой stdout вовремя и мы не можем дождаться. попробуйте без `local $/` читать построчно `while(<$read>)` и сразу выводить. интересно, хоть одну строку отдаст или нет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87588/discussion-between-usr13-and-mike).